# Convergence and Continuity Generic function f

Tags: real-analysis

Real Analysis: Solve by formal prove. If f is an arbitrary function and p1, p2, ... is a sequence of points in the domain of f converging to the number x in the domain of f, and f is continuous at (x,f(x)), then f(p1), f(p2) ... converges to x.

Proof:

Let f be a function s.t. it is continuous at (x,f(x))

Let p1,p2, ... be a sequence of points in the domain converging to x in the domain of f

Then there is an arbitrary open interval S=(A,B) containing f(x) and there is an open interval T=(a,b) containing x s.t.  t is an element of T, t is in the domain of f, and f(t) is an element of S (our class' definition of continuous)

Then there is an arbitrary open interval U=(c,d) containing x, so there is some positive integer N s.t. n<=N, so pn is an element of U (our class' definition of converging to a point)

(This is where I have trouble, I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm sorry about my lack of skills about this website. I am new to it.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of typos, especially with (co)domains and some quantifier problems.

Here is a cleaned up version of your proof(And the last line):

**what is the codomain/domain here? I will let $X,Y$ be metric spaces.**

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a function continuous at $x \in X$

Let $(p_n) \to x$ be a sequence converging to $x$.

**start with $S$ arbitrary, you want to show that $f(p_n) \in S$ for sufficiently large $n$:**

Let $S$ be an arbitrary interval containing $f(x)$. By the assumption on continuity, there exists an interval $T$ containing x so that $f(T) \subset S$.

**Note that I replaced $S$ by $T$ in the following sentence:**

So there is some positive integer $N$ so that $p_n\in T$ for all $n \geq N$.

Then, $f(p_n) \in S$ for all $n \geq N$, as desired.

Comment: All I know is that the domain is all reals. And thank you, I knew it is a very simple problem and for the most part I knew the intuition for it, I just didn't know what else to say.

Comment: well write $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and the rest is exactly the same.

Comment: What does that symbol mean? The one that is like the subset without the line under it?

Comment: No, I mean choose the domain/codomain appropriately so that you can write your proof.

Comment: I get that, but I dont understand in your proof where it says "f(T) 'sidewaysU' S" Does that symbol mean subset?

Comment: yes, ,it means subset.

Comment: Could you actually explain to me why T is a subset of S?